# Slow SSH & Firezilla OSX

Tags: macos, ssh, ftp

Im having a bizzare issue with my Macbook pro running el capitan 10.11.3 (15D21) where if i try to SSH or use FTP like firezilla, i can connect to the ip addresses but at a snails pace.

SSH, when connected in terminal the typing is slow, changing directories is slow and sometimes itll stall and then type out after ive pressed keys.

FTP with firezilla is the same using SFTP, connecting is slow and loading folers is slow but the download speeds are quick as hell

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,

Turns out the work network over wifi was hating my laptop so switched to wired